# After Cloning Project from Bitbucket Xcode Project Navigator Does not showing some Groups and Its files

Tags: swift, xcode

All files Are present on Bitbucket Remote , but when i Clone Project and open in Xcode inside Project navigator some groups are missing. but when i check in finder Their Files Are present. Can Anyone Help me out why this happening.[image]

[image: able to find file in finder but not in Xcode.]

Comment: pbxproj file has the references to the folder groups and you probably didn't update it on the bitbucket.

Comment: is there any way i can fix this.

Comment: Add those folders manually now and don't select checkbox "Copy items if needed". And this time don't ignore `pbxproj` file in your commit to the bitbucket.